# Implementing parent class methods with several children class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, parent, children

I have a class (let's call it `A`) that is extended by several children class (`B`, `C`, `D`, etc.).

In each child class, there are specific methods that I'd like to be accessible from an instantiation of the parent class `A`.

I tried to declare `A` as an abstract class, and to declare each child class methods inside as abstract. Then I implemented these methods in their own class but it seems that each child class must implement every method of the parent class. However, I can't do this.

Would you have an idea for this issue?

Comment: Can you give any more detail about what you are trying to do? What code have you written so far? Do `B`, `C` and `D` all implement the same abstract method or do they implement different ones?

Comment: Yes, the thing is that they implement different ones. Basically, the abstract class A contains the declaration of abstract methods m1, m2, m3, m4, m5... Class B implements m1, m2; class C implements m3, class D implements m4, m5. Hope it's clear enough. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

`In each children class, there are specific methods that I'd like to be accessible from an instantiation of the parent class A.`

That's not the point of inheritance. Even if you could do this, it shows that your design is broken.

Comment: Oh. I'm not an expert in Java, I didn't know it wasn't possible. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not possible, I'm saying don't do it.